# ftp connector when used as source in flow acts like?

Tags: mule

I want to know if I can use a `ftp inbound connector` as a source in a flow ?
 New `ftp` server is created message is initiated when a file is uploaded or does it connect to ftp server and checks for new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It connects to an existing FTP server and polls it.

Comment: thanks for your reply
does mule change file on FTP server once the updated file gets downloaded and a new message is created?

Comment: The Enterprise Edition of the FTP transport allows to move the file on the remote server: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/ftp-transport-reference#mule-enterprise-connector-attributes For the Community Edition, you'll have to create a custom component to do it.